# How to remove duplication from UITableView sections Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am having issue in removing duplicate from section of tableview. I am using 2 section so I want to remove duplication of items from second section which are already available in section 1 so kindly guide me about it? I am using two array which are coming from sql server using WCF web-service. Here is my `cellforrowAt` code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell : UITableViewCell!


if tableView == self.diseasetableview
{
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diseasenamecell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell

cell1.selecteddiseasename.text = selectedDiseaseName[indexPath.row]
    cell = cell1

}
if tableView == self.foodtableview
{
    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        print(indexPath.section)
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodnamecell", for: indexPath) as! FoodnameTableCell

   cell2.foodnamelbl.text = food[indexPath.row]
    cell = cell2
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1
    {

        print(indexPath.section)
        print(notRecomended[indexPath.row])

        let cell3 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodnamecell", for: indexPath) as! FoodnameTableCell

            cell3.foodnamelbl.text = notRecomended[indexPath.row]
            cell = cell3


    }

}
return cell
```

}

Comment: Check and remove the duplicates in the controller **before** reloading the table view. Or filter the duplicates right after receiving the data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a filered array using the below code and for that section use filtered array

```
     let notRecomended = ["food1", "food3", "food4", "food2", "food6","food2"]
     let food = ["food1", "food2"]
     let filteredResult = notRecomended.filter { !food.contains($0) }) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for duplicates in your second array and remove duplicates items.

```
secondArray = secondArray.filter {firstArray.contains($0) == false}
```

Comment: i would love to but my reputation is not enough if you don't mind vote up for my question 

Comment: Oh I was not aware of that.